# inserting into index location of a text file if a string does exist inside the line, if the string doesn't exist, still write line as it was

Tags: c#, string

The program is supposed to look for a string in a line, and if it finds the string, it will make the inserts after meeting the condition inside the textfile. Currently, when I run this program it is now simply giving me a blank console. Previously, I had it just reading all the lines properly and could make inserts only if I remove them first but it messed the indexing up and ultimately did not give me the result I wanted. The logic is fairly straightforward, if you see any problems please share your thoughts. Please and thanks. I am very confused why this is having problems and not working.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Masker 
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            string path = @"\file1.txt";
            ReadLines(path)

        }
        public static void ReadLines(string path) 
        {
            int counter = 0;
            var text = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (string s in File.ReadAllLines(path)) 
            {
                counter += 1;
                if (s.Contains("000INDEX"))
                {
                    text.AppendLine(s.Insert(60, "#")); 
                } 
                else if (s.Contains("001PRTBNR")) 
                {
                    text.AppendLine(s.Insert(60, "#").Insert(119,"#").Insert(120,"#").Insert(121, "#"));
                    
                };
                text.AppendLine(s);
                //Console.Write(text.ToString());
            }
            Console.Write(text.ToString());
        }
       

    }
}
```

Comment: Try something like this:  string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
        foreach(string s in readText)  and probably dont need the while loop

Comment: Then leave the if statements as is? Cause this was my initial approach, and I was getting no changes in the original textfile

Comment: well, i will remove the first two

Comment: Yeah the more I think about this answer the less helpful it is. Making it string[] removes the use of the Insert function which is what I am trying to do here.

Comment: Can you make a code block to explain more thoroughly, I am having a hard time understanding what/where you mean

Answer (score 0):

The last two blocks of your if/else statement will never be executed.
If the execution reaches the third check

> else if (s.Contains("000INDEX"))

that will always be true. Because if it wasn't, then the first check

> if (!s.Contains("000INDEX"))

would have already been true.

But the biggest problem is that if the line contains "000INDEX", your while loop becomes and infinite loop. You never leave it. That is probably the reason why you end up with a blank console.

Comment: I tried it without those two earlier and got it to compile, but nothing was inserted into the textfile.

Comment: They don't do any harm (except for making the code more difficult to read). So removing them won't change anything. The problem is the infinite loop.
I said earlier it will be an infinite loop if the line contains "000INDEX" but in fact it will always be an infinit loop because you never reach the break.

Comment: Whats an alternative to the if statements then? Because I am trying to read through 10000+ lines

Comment: What are the cases you are trying to cover when analysing a line?
Currently you have (in order of your code)
- line doesn't contain 000INDEX
- line contains 000INDEX but not 001PRTBNR
- line contains 000INDEX and 001PRTBNR
- line contains 000INDEX and 001PRTBNR (again)
- else

I know that your checks in the code don't read like that but it indirectly follows.
So in code your second check simply says "the line doesn't contain 001PRTBNR".  But since it can only get there, if the first check is false, we know that the line must contain 000INDEX at this point. Does that makes sense?

Comment: I think I am following. The goal I am trying to achieve is replacing the differences in two files, but I was instructed to do this without using comparisons as the main driver. So, my thought process was that I would simply need to read each line, then check if the line has one of the two tags ( 000INDEX and  001PRTBNR) and if the line does, it will edit the line by inserting "#" into the indexed spots.

Spots are (record,pos,len) here:
INDEX , 60, 15
INDEX , 163, 10
INDEX ,941,10
PRTBNR, 60, 1
PRTBNR, 119, 244

Comment: Those spots are the characters that need to change in each line with one of the two tags. Does that make more sense?

Comment: I see how it would be confusing from the example, I am using string builder rather than making inserts into the actual text file itself, but that was giving me little to no results. Was just continuously checking an unchanged textfile.